# highchart drill down break bar chart after change title

Tags: highcharts

Highchart inner chart bars are break after trying 2-3 times drill up and drill down.
My first chart in donut chart and then inner chart is bar chart.

So, I need to show legend and hide title in pie chart (First) and then want to remove legend and show title in drill down - bar chart (Second).

```
var options = {
    chart: {
        type: 'column',
        renderTo: div,
        backgroundColor: '#191919',
        events: {
            drilldown: function(e) {
                this.yAxis[0].setTitle({
                    text: 'Total'
                });
            },
            drillup: function(e) {
                this.yAxis[0].setTitle({text: ''});
            }
        }
    },
    
}
```

The issue is shown in the below image:

[image]

Comment: Could you reproduce your issue with the sample data on some online editor?

Comment: try with drill up and down 2-3 times for different section.

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/h8fjtkna/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the bug occurs when you have used the Highstock script rather than Highcharts. While using the Highcharts script everything works fine.

```
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>
```

Demo: https://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/4eus1x5t/

Comment: But I need to run highstock.js. Isn't it possible with the same?

Comment: @KamalSanghavi I am afraid that it is impossible - Highstock inherits a lot of properties from the Highcharts script, but not everything which makes that the drilldown module is not compatible with it.

Comment: when i using highcharts.js in my project, it will shows some unwanted 0 (Zeros) when drill up.

Comment: @KamalSanghavi could you reproduce this issue on the online editor?

Comment: for now I change my js from highstock to highchart for that page only and it is working fine now. Thanks.